# Nodejs performing task on fixed time in the future

Tags: node.js

I have stumbled upon a difficult type of problem for me. So, lets say we have an API, which creates events in the future, for example, after two weeks from this moment. During this time, we can post comments, add photos, etc. on this event. After those two week pass, I want to close this event and change it's type from 'OPEN' to 'CLOSED'. How should I achieve this?

I have tried [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) library for this task, but it seems that it is for different purpose of tasks - scheduled tasks. Are there any other options or other practices to do this?

I am using postgres database, if that's helpful.

Comment: PgAgent helps to schedule tasks inside PostgreSQL. You could also use CRON tasks if you are working with linux.

Comment: @Ariel yes, but I need a code implementation, because it is going to be a lot of events, thousands of them. What I mean by event is that it should be something like Facebook events for example, which are scheduled to happen in the future.